# How to check CPU utilization of Linux kernel networking?

Tags: linux, networking

I implemented a "bridge" on my home network where I've got

```
ISP <--1Gb Internet--> Router <--1GbE--> Linux Workstation <--40GbE DAC/Fiber--> Windows PC
```

by following this guide: https://medium.com/@TarunChinmai/sharing-internet-connection-from-a-linux-machine-over-ethernet-a5cbbd775a4f

To my surprise, this seems to be working great and I can get nominal internet performance via speed tests on the PC, while allowing internet to still work properly on the workstation machine.

I was trying to see what the routing load is on the workstation machine, but I've got a pretty modern CPU in there and I cannot see a blip at all in `sudo top`, `sudo htop`, `sudo btop`, I even tried `sudo perf top` when pushing an internet based network load.

This is all purely to satisfy my curiosity. Are there other tools I can use to check? I kind of feel like kernel cpu time is not a metric these tools are providing me with. But maybe it could be possible that there's just next to no processing load and it's not enough to become visible, and in this absence of a performance problem I should stop investigating.

Comment: https://people.kernel.org/dsahern/the-cpu-cost-of-networking-on-a-host